# Can I go below a VB6 TextBox control's minimum height enforced by the used font?

Tags: winapi, vb6

I have a TextBox control restricted to numeric input. Its font is Arial, Standard, 10 pt. The container's ScaleMode is set to pixels.

Since the textbox will accept and display only numbers, I do not need all that whitespace around, especially not in the vertical dimension, so I resize the TextBox' height in the designer. My goal is a 20 pixels tall TextBox control.

Attempting to set the Height property in the property window snaps the height to 24 pixels.

It is obvious, that the control's height is enforced by the used font. Using Arial, Standard, 7 pt., I can have my desired height of 20 px. Only that I need a font size of 10 pt.

When using the mouse, resizing works in the designer (for example can I achieve 19 pixels). But at run-time, the height is back to 24 pixels.

I've tried to trick VB in the Initialize event by first giving it a small font, sizing the height, then reset the font size to the original. Nope, 24 pixels.

I also tried to use Window's API function MoveWindow. The box displays at 24 pixels.

Is there any other possibly helpful API function, or is my only possibility to write an own VB user control? (I can make a user control consisting of a TextBox control as its only constituent control, then place its Top into the negative, and the user control's height to the desired height.)

Comment: I'm not sure why, but it would appear that if you delete the existing textbox, add a new one, assign the height using the mouse (not the property grid) and only then set the font to Arial 10pt, it will stay at the low height at runtime. Doing this in a different order will reset the height.

Comment: *"Attempting to set the Height property in the property window snaps the height to 24 pixels."* - That's because the height is set in DLUs (see [About Arranging Controls on Dialog Boxes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa232403(v=vs.60).aspx)).

Comment: @GSerg, you are right, +1 for finding this - only that I won't using it: it seems worse than a hack, because of the "we don't know why it works." (Maybe it's a 19 years old bug which will be fixed with the next update...)

Comment: @IInspectable, I don't use a dialog box.

Comment: @Herb: If you are using the resource editor then you are creating a dialog. It may be called *Form* in VB6, but it uses the same API calls to create it from a resource script, like any other dialog. The same rules apply, like measuring elements in DLUs (not pixels).

Comment: @IInspectable, thank you, now re-reading your link makes more sense to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so I went the stony road and created a user control suitable for me. Should you have the same problem, then this one solves it.

Add a new project of type ActiveX user control. Name the user control UTextBox. Modify the user control's font to what we want (Arial, Standard, 10 pt.), and set its ScaleMode property to pixels. Save the 2 files into a new project folder.

Place a TextBox control at position 0, 0 of the user control, and name it cTextBox. Then the whole core functionality is contained in the Resize event.

```
Option Explicit

'==============================================================================
'On resizing the control.
'------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Private Sub UserControl_Resize()
    Dim lHeightDiff As Long

    With cTextBox
        'Let the TextBox control inherit the user control's new dimensions.
        .Height = UserControl.ScaleHeight
        .Width = UserControl.ScaleWidth

        'The text box is always centered vertically on the same-sized or smaller
        'user control, so that the text still is displayed also when the
        'TextBox is larger than the user control's height.
        .Top = (UserControl.ScaleHeight - .Height) / 2
    End With
End Sub
'==============================================================================
```

Next is the tedious task to pass to and from the text box control all properties, methods and events, or at least all those you are interested in.

```
'==============================================================================
'Pass-through properties. Keep it alphabetical.
'------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Public Property Let Alignment(NewAlignment As AlignmentConstants)
    cTextBox.Alignment = NewAlignment
    PropertyChanged "Alignment"
End Property
'------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Public Property Get Alignment() As AlignmentConstants
    Alignment = cTextBox.Alignment
End Property
'------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Public Property Let Enabled(NewState As Boolean)
    cTextBox.Enabled = NewState
    PropertyChanged "Enabled"
End Property
'------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Public Property Get Enabled() As Boolean
    Enabled = cTextBox.Enabled
End Property
'------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Public Property Get hWnd() As Long      'Read-only.
    hWnd = cTextBox.hWnd
End Property
'------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Public Property Let Text(NewText As String)
    cTextBox.Text = NewText
    PropertyChanged "Text"
End Property

...     
'==============================================================================
```

There are (at least) two special properties which should be intercepted and applied onto the user control itself: Appearance and BorderStyle, because the text box can be placed outside the user control and would make these properties partially invisible. For these 2 properties, I was not able to locate their enumerations as shown in the property window, and consequently rolled own ones (there exists a naming convention, use your own names if you wish):

```
'==============================================================================
'Enumerations.
'------------------------------------------------------------------------------
'Used with the public Appearance property.
Public Enum ETxB_Appearance
    TxBApp_2D = 0&
    TxBApp_3D = 1&
End Enum
'------------------------------------------------------------------------------
'Used with the public BorderStyle property.
Public Enum ETxB_BorderStyle
    TxBBSt_None = 0&
    TxBBSt_FixedSingle = 1&
End Enum
'==============================================================================
```

These are the 2 special properties:

```
'==============================================================================
'All properties, methods and events which are currently needed are mediated
'to and from the outside world and the TextBox control, with the exception of
'BorderStyle and Appearance, which are properties of the user control, so that
'a frame can be displayed even when it would not fit into the TextBox control.
'------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Public Property Let Appearance(NewAppearance As ETxB_Appearance)
    UserControl.Appearance = NewAppearance
    PropertyChanged "Appearance"
End Property
'------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Public Property Get Appearance() As ETxB_Appearance
    Appearance = UserControl.Appearance
End Property
'------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Public Property Let BorderStyle(NewStyle As ETxB_BorderStyle)
    UserControl.BorderStyle = NewStyle
    PropertyChanged "BorderStyle"
End Property
'------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Public Property Get BorderStyle() As ETxB_BorderStyle
    BorderStyle = UserControl.BorderStyle
End Property
'==============================================================================
```

Now do the same for all **methods**.

And now for all **events** (and of course you need to add Event declarations as well.)

Finally, don't let's forget to happily code the property bag routines to make your user control have persistent properties.

```
'==============================================================================
'Initializing properties.
'------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Private Sub UserControl_InitProperties()
    UserControl.Appearance = TxBApp_2D
    ...
    cTextBox.Alignment = vbLeftJustify
    ...
End Sub
'==============================================================================

'==============================================================================
'Reading properties.
'------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Private Sub UserControl_ReadProperties(PropBag As PropertyBag)
    With PropBag
        UserControl.Appearance = .ReadProperty("Appearance", TxBApp_2D)
        ...
        cTextBox.Alignment = .ReadProperty("Alignment", vbLeftJustify)
        ...
    End With
End Sub
'==============================================================================

'==============================================================================
'Write properties.
'------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Private Sub UserControl_WriteProperties(PropBag As PropertyBag)
    With PropBag
        .WriteProperty "Appearance", UserControl.Appearance, TxBApp_2D
        ...
        .WriteProperty "Alignment", cTextBox.Alignment, vbLeftJustify
        ...
    End With
End Sub
'==============================================================================
```

Now the automatic minimum height enforcement is gone. For example can we fit our standard 10 pt Font into a 14 pixels tall control.

[image: Text box without minimum height]

Comment: Wow, you *really* wanted those 4 pixels back!